# In Eclipse, how to close the open files(editors) when exiting without auto-load in next startup

Tags: eclipse, autostart

a problem troubled me for several days. Would like to find the answer here... Thanks ahead!

I developed a plugin in Eclipse. When it starts up, it will open the files (with specific editors we developed) left at the last exiting. I wonder whether I can disable this auto-starting in code?

BTW, I have tried the option "Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Close editors automatically", however, with useless result.

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the 'Restore editor state on statup'?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't works. The function of "Restore editor state on startup" is to restore the cursor state/position for the  active page. However, the files are all opened already.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already creating your own `WorkbenchAdvisor` (if you're creating an RCP application), you have access to the workbench configurer which can change this property:

```
public void initialize (IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
    super.initialize (configurer);
    getWorkbenchConfigurer ().setSaveAndRestore (false);
}
```

For a non-RCP application (ie: just a plugin), it's not recommended to do this since it is a global setting that will affect all editors. It can still be done though:

```
public void disableReopenEditors () {
    String pref = org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.CLOSE_EDITORS_ON_EXIT;
    PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(pref, true);
}
```

If you want to do it manually, you can follow [Where does Eclipse save the list of files to open on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481089/where-does-eclipse-save-the-list-of-files-to-open-on-startup) to delete the file the workbench uses to store this information.