# How to close all tabs on Eclipse exit?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

There is a CDT Qt plugin that hangs everything on startup if a C++ file is open.

How to make Eclipse start with all files closed?

Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3) 20180607-0625

Comment: Before exiting, right click a tab and Close All?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2481089/9247260) helps you. It shows where the workbench settings are located.